# Confirming my procedure while doing a surface integral.

Tags: integration

"The area bounded by the curve r = 2R cos θ has a surface charge density: $$σ(r, θ)=σ\frac{r}{R}sin^4θ$$
What is the total amount of charge?"

This was a seemingly easy question in an assignment that stumped me. I know it's a physics question, but I was stuck on the math.

My procedure:

Now, the given surface is a circle. Since charge density was given, I just had to integrate over the surface of the circle. Is it correct if I just write $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2Rcos\theta}\sigma(r,\theta)rdrd\theta$ ? Or is there any other way to do this?

My answer came out to be $\frac{32\sigma R^2}{105}$, but I'm not sure if it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polar coordinates are the natural way to integrate the total given the functional forms of the boundary and the density. You have the right set up and the result

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2Rcos\theta}\sigma(r,\theta)rdrd\theta$$

$$=\frac{\sigma}{R}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^4\theta \int_0^{2Rcos\theta}r^2drd\theta$$
$$=\frac{8\sigma R^2}{3}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^4\theta\cos^3\theta d\theta$$

$$=\frac{8\sigma R^2}{3}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(\sin^4\theta - \sin^6\theta)d(\sin\theta) $$

$$=\frac{8\sigma R^2}{3}\left(\frac25 - \frac27\right)=\frac{32}{105}\sigma R^2$$